# How to use native API from fabric crashlytics?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm seeing native crashes on my Android app, but I'm able to search them directly. What I did for regular java exception crashes was add the User ID as one of the keys, so that I can search on each crash later. However, it seems that this doesn't apply to native crashes caught by crashlytics?

So then I found something like: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#custom-logs-and-keys-mechanics where it seems you can add the user ID and other key-value info, which i'm assuming will then make the crash searchable (on fabric dashboard). However, how does this work if I have multiple native libraries? Am i supposed to include this crashlytics NDK in every single native library?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I just tested this out with a sample app, and it turns out, no matter where the crash happens, as long as a key-value pair is set beforehand, it will stick it to that crash thread.